# How to modify path where Torch Hub models are downloaded

Tags: path, pytorch

When I download models through Torch Hub, models are automatically downloaded in `/home/me/.cache/torch`.

**How can I modify this behavior ?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html#where-are-my-downloaded-models-saved), there is several ways to modify this path.
In priority order :

1. Calling hub.set_dir(<PATH_TO_HUB_DIR>)
2. $TORCH_HOME/hub, if environment variable TORCH_HOME is set.
3. $XDG_CACHE_HOME/torch/hub, if environment variable XDG_CACHE_HOME is set.
4. ~/.cache/torch/hub

So I just had to do :

`export TORCH_HOME=/my/path/`

---

#### Edit

`TORCH_HUB` appear to be deprecated, use `TORCH_HOME` instead

Comment: `export TORCH_HOME=/my/path/` did the job.